# Rendering wordcloud in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise

I am trying to create a wordcloud inside a React container using this [library](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js). The wordcloud works when passed the array `test`.

I would like to call an api to get the words for the wordcloud and then pass it to the wordcloud library. Below is the code I am using to fetch from the api an array of `words` and then pass to the wordcloud library.

```
function getWords() {
  return fetch('http://bio-wordcloud-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/getWords/?format=json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    return responseJson;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

When debugging the return value in chrome, I see that elements in the response value are `undefined`. Here is the component:

```
import WordCloud from 'wordcloud'
class WordCloudComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    var words = getWords();
    var wordList = []
    words.then(function(value) {
      value.map(function(object){
        wordList.push ([object.word,object.weight]);
      });
    });
    this.setState({words: wordList});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas)
    var test = [["foo", 12], ["bar", 6]];
    var words = this.state.words;
    console.log(words);
    console.log(test)

    WordCloud(canvas, { list: test, color: "random-dark", shape: "circle", color:"green", wait: 0, backgroundColor:"black"});
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <div className={styles.cloudCanvasContainer}>
      <canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My console logs show that both words and tests are arrays containing arrays of words and weight. As this is my first time using React/ Promises, I am unsure as to what is going wrong. Could someone please explain?

Comment: two questions: is `responseJson` undefined  before being returned? did you try without `catch`?

Comment: 1)It is an array. 2)Negative @DamienLeroux

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `this.setState({words: wordList});` happens instantaneously after you *asynchronously* invoke `getWords`. In other words, `wordList` isn't yet populated with the returned results of the API when you `setState`. Instead, you should update your state only after you callback from the async API.

```
  componentWillMount () {
    getWords().then(function(value) {
      this.setState({
        words: value.map((obj) => [obj.word, obj.weight])
      });
    });
  }
```

Modifying your logic like this also eliminates stateful mutation of the `wordsList` variable defined outside of the scope of your promise callback.

Comment: I get the following errors when trying the new method: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of null(…)`
***and***  `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined(…)`

Comment: The errors are coming from the function `getWords`. responseJson is not being returned

Comment: Ah, my bad--you need to bind your top-level callback: function(value) { ... }.bind(this) . Or use an ES6 arrow function: (value) => {}. The scope of your outer `this` gets lost in the callback.

Comment: But you are also correct about `responseJson`. You cannot simply return the value in your callback, as the return value gets lost. You should instead resolve the promise passing `responseJson` as a callback parameter.